# Iterate over data set and insert sequence ids for rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a data set with more than 2 million rows in a Oracle SQL table and want to do some association analysis on this. To apply a sequence mining algorithm to this data, I need a column named 'sequenceId' and a column 'eventId'.

The table structure looks like this:

- time
- pId
- uId

Now I need an id that increments every time the uId changes. How can I do that in Oracle SQL? I tried it in R but it takes more than 12 hours there...

---

Sample data:

| time | pId | uId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-10-01 12:12:24 | 3806 | 535447446 |
| 2019-10-01 19:51:55 | 3762 | 535447446 |
| 2019-10-02 18:09:34 | 3806 | 552286734 |
| 2019-10-02 17:54:01 | 3928 | 493964166 |

Expected result:

| time | pId | uId | sequence id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-10-01 12:12:24 | 3806 | 535447446 | 1 |
| 2019-10-01 19:51:55 | 3762 | 535447446 | 1 |
| 2019-10-02 18:09:34 | 3806 | 552286734 | 2 |
| 2019-10-02 17:54:01 | 3928 | 493964166 | 3 |

The id should increment when the user_id changes

Comment: "...id that increments every time the user_id changes..." -- according to timestamp, product_id, combination of both? Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: no, only when the user_id changes. added data and expected result :)

Comment: Sounds like you need a `sequence.nextval` and a trigger that compares specific fields `for each row` on insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
source_data AS (
    SELECT '2019-10-01 12:12:24' AS timestamp, 3806 AS product_id, 535447446 AS user_id FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-10-01 19:51:55', 3762, 535447446 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-10-02 18:09:34', 3806, 552286734 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-10-02 17:54:01', 3928, 493964166 FROM DUAL 
),
cte AS (
    SELECT timestamp,
           product_id,
           user_id,
           CASE WHEN user_id = LAG(user_id) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) 
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1
                END new_user
    FROM source_data
)
SELECT timestamp,
       product_id,
       user_id,
       SUM(new_user) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) sequence_id
FROM cte;
```

> | TIMESTAMP | PRODUCT_ID | USER_ID | SEQUENCE_ID |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2019-10-01 12:12:24 | 3806 | 535447446 | 1 |
> | 2019-10-01 19:51:55 | 3762 | 535447446 | 1 |
> | 2019-10-02 17:54:01 | 3928 | 493964166 | 2 |
> | 2019-10-02 18:09:34 | 3806 | 552286734 | 3 |

Comment: looks like a nice solution, but do I have to write every single row in the 'WITH source_data AS (...)' part? that's impossible for two million rows

Comment: *do I have to write every single row in the 'WITH source_data AS (...)' part?* No, this is a table with source data only. You should use your working table with the data instead.

Comment: I tried it with this _WITH  source_data AS (SELECT timestamp AS timestamp, product_id AS product_id, user_id AS user_id FROM <mytable> ORDER BY user_id
), ..._ and the sequence_ids are successfully generated, but they are not fitting to the user_ids... sometimes it's correct, but sometimes there is the same sequence_id for a different user_id...

Comment: maybe it is helpful to note that the timestamp and the product_id are completely irrelevant, the sequence_id is not depending on one of them

Comment: @testystaxky Provide online fiddle with your data and reproduced issue.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=51cee8f6a243ea8b2afe2741bb99a2e3

Comment: @testystaxky In your fiddle there are rows with absolutely the same `EVENT_TIME` value. In this case there is no way to define what is relative posession of such rows, noway to determine what row is before and what one is after (visual rows ordering during SELECT is virtual and not exists really). You must expand ordering expression in this case, the expression must provide each row uniqueness. If not then the result will be indefinite always. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8c87d5379fb810cd135ea22ce4361f34

Comment: I LOVE YOU! I don't know why, but somehow it worked now without a new id as in your fiddle. I'm so thankful!!